# Removing multiple DOM's using onclick target

Tags: javascript

I cant figure out how to delete all the elements in one click, it takes three clicks. And i get why, there is three elements in my li. I have tried alot of different approaches but allwas three clicks to remove the `<li>`

```
function newItem(name, value, payed, id) {
    if(payed == true){
        return;
    }
    var ul = document.getElementById("list");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name + ' ' + value));
    li.setAttribute("id", id);
    li.innerHTML = `<table><tr><td>${name}</td><td>${value}kr</td>`;
    ul.appendChild(li);
    bill = document.getElementById("billName").value = "";
    billVal = document.getElementById("billValue").value = ""; 
    li.onclick = removeItem;
}

function removeItem(event) {
    element = event.target;
    element.remove();
    data[element.id].payed = true;
    data[element.id].value = JSON.stringify(0);
    localStorage.setItem("Bills", JSON.stringify(data));
    location.reload();
  }
```

Comment: Why is the page being reloaded?

Comment: Did you debug your click event back to it's propagination? Maybe you have some other event handling or conflict that is missleading the event... Can you provide a working example so we can investigate?

Comment: I'd suggest you want to use `element = event.currentTarget;`

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica, Awsome.. works just fine! Thanks alot!

Comment: If no one offers a good explanation by the time I get home I'll offer an answer as to why it works, and why your original approach failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your own code didn't seem to work was because of the — apparent — misunderstanding of `event.target`; this is the property of the `Event` Object that identifies the element on which the event was first fired/detected, from which the event can bubble up to the ancestor that is assigned as the `EventTarget` to which the event-listener function was bound, using `EventTarget.addEventListener()`.

Given the following example:

```js
// here we're using a generator function to generate an
// incrementing numeric counter to use for the element-
// id; assigning a default value to the 'initial' variable
// in the event one is not supplied:
let idGenerator = function*(initial = 0) {
    // here we use a horrible approach to allow the
    // function to generate an infinite sequence of
    // of numbers (note this does not cause an
    // infinite loop)
    while (true) {
      // we yield the value of the initial variable,
      // and then increment that value for the next
      // iteration of the generator:
      yield initial++;
    }
  },

  // initialising the generator function:
  idGen = idGenerator( document.querySelectorAll('#list li').length ),
  // I don't enjoy typing 'document.createElement(...)'
  // repeatedly, so a helper functiont takes of that for
  // me:
  create = (el) => {
    return document.createElement(el);
  },
  // a reference to a <button> that exists in order to
  // add new contents to the <ul> element:
  button = document.querySelector('#add'),

  // function that will both create, and append those
  // new elements; using Arrow syntax:
  createElement = () => {
    // creating the elements using the helper function:
    const li = create('li'),
      span = create('span'),
      h2 = create('h2'),

      // getting the new id-value from the generator:
      id = idGen.next().value;

    // iterating over the created elements using
    // Array.prototype.forEach() along with an Arrow
    // function:
    [li, span, h2].forEach(
      // 'el' is a reference to the current element in the
      // Array of Elements over which we're iterating:
      (el) => {
        // caching a reference to the type of element:
        let tag = el.tagName.toLowerCase();

        // here we use the Element.dataset API to add a custom
        // data-* attribute and value to the Element, here it's
        // the tag-name of the element (for visualisation
        // purposes later):
        el.dataset.tag = tag;
        // and here we set the text-content of the Element, so
        // that each element has a unique text and is easily
        // identifiable:
        el.textContent = `${tag}-element: ${id}`;
      })

    // appending the child-elements to their parents:
    h2.append(span);
    li.append(h2);

    // binding the removeItem() function as the 'click'
    // event-handler for the <li> element:
    li.addEventListener('click', removeItem);

    // appending the <li> to the <ul>:
    document.querySelector('#list').append(li);
  };

// the 'event' Object is passed automatically from the
// EventTarget.AddEventListener() function:
function removeItem(event) {

  // we get a reference to the element upon which
  // the relevant event was initiated:
  const element = event.target;
  // here we update the color of that element, in order to show
  // where the click was detected and to more easily illustrate
  // what the 'event.target' is:
  element.style.color = '#f90';
  
  // here we also assign a class-name to the clicked element:
  element.classList.add('clicked');
  
  // here we add a custom-property ('CSS variable') to - again -
  // make it instantly clear upon which Element the event was
  // detected:
  element.style.setProperty('--clickedElement', `"${element.tagName.toLowerCase()}"`);
}

// binding the createElement() function as the event-handler
// for the 'click' event:
button.addEventListener('click', createElement);

// iterating over the existing <li> elements and binding the
// event-handler to them:
document.querySelectorAll('#list li').forEach(
    (el) => el.addEventListener('click', removeItem)
);
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body * {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

body [data-tag]::before {
  content: ' (' attr(data-tag) ') ';
  color: #999;
}

h2 {
  align-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.clicked::after {
  content: 'You clicked on the: ' var(--clickedElement, 'span');
  color: limegreen;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: block;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list" data-tag="ul">
  <li data-tag="li">li-element: 0
    <h2 data-tag="h2">h2-element: 0
      <span data-tag="span">span-element: 0</span>
    </h2>
  </li>
  <li data-tag="li">li-element: 1
    <h2 data-tag="h2">h2-element: 1
      <span data-tag="span">span-element: 1</span>
    </h2>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="add">Add &lt;li&gt; elements</button>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7p6m1aL3/).

What the above demo — and [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7p6m1aL3/) should illustrate is that clicking on the content of the `<li>` element doesn't necessarily mean that the `<li>` is itself the `event.target`. The reason for so much visualisation in the demos is to show how easy it is to click the 'wrong' thing.

There are two ways of working around this, one is to use `event.currentTarget` (which returns the element upon which the event-listener was bound) or the second — if you know enough about the structure of the DOM — is to use `event.target.closest('li')` (as an example) if you're certain that the `<li>` element is the one you wish to select.

As an illustration of the use of `Element.closest()`:

```js
// here we're using a generator function to generate an
// incrementing numeric counter to use for the element-
// id; assigning a default value to the 'initial' variable
// in the event one is not supplied:
let idGenerator = function*(initial = 0) {
    // here we use a horrible approach to allow the
    // function to generate an infinite sequence of
    // of numbers (note this does not cause an
    // infinite loop)
    while (true) {
      // we yield the value of the initial variable,
      // and then increment that value for the next
      // iteration of the generator:
      yield initial++;
    }
  },

  // initialising the generator function:
  idGen = idGenerator(document.querySelectorAll('#list li').length),
  // I don't enjoy typing 'document.createElement(...)'
  // repeatedly, so a helper functiont takes of that for
  // me:
  create = (el) => {
    return document.createElement(el);
  },
  // a reference to a <button> that exists in order to
  // add new contents to the <ul> element:
  button = document.querySelector('#add'),

  // function that will both create, and append those
  // new elements; using Arrow syntax:
  createElement = () => {
    // creating the elements using the helper function:
    const li = create('li'),
      span = create('span'),
      h2 = create('h2'),

      // getting the new id-value from the generator:
      id = idGen.next().value;

    // iterating over the created elements using
    // Array.prototype.forEach() along with an Arrow
    // function:
    [li, span, h2].forEach(
      // 'el' is a reference to the current element in the
      // Array of Elements over which we're iterating:
      (el) => {
        // caching a reference to the type of element:
        let tag = el.tagName.toLowerCase();

        // here we use the Element.dataset API to add a custom
        // data-* attribute and value to the Element, here it's
        // the tag-name of the element (for visualisation
        // purposes later):
        el.dataset.tag = tag;
        // and here we set the text-content of the Element, so
        // that each element has a unique text and is easily
        // identifiable:
        el.textContent = `${tag}-element: ${id}`;
      })

    // appending the child-elements to their parents:
    h2.append(span);
    li.append(h2);

    // binding the removeItem() function as the 'click'
    // event-handler for the <li> element:
    li.addEventListener('click', removeItem);

    // appending the <li> to the <ul>:
    document.querySelector('#list').append(li);
  };

// the 'event' Object is passed automatically from the
// EventTarget.AddEventListener() function:
function removeItem(event) {

  // we get a reference to the element upon which
  // the relevant event was initiated and, from there,
  // navigate upwards through the DOM until we encounter
  // an ancestor-element which matches the CSS selector
  // passed to the Element.closest() method (if no element
  // exists this will return null; hence it's best to
  // validate the existence of an Element relying upon it):
  const element = event.target.closest('li');
  // here we update the color of that element, in order to show
  // where the click was detected and to more easily illustrate
  // what the 'event.target' is:
  element.style.color = '#f90';

  // here we also assign a class-name to the clicked element:
  element.classList.add('clicked');

  // here we add a custom-property ('CSS variable') to - again -
  // make it instantly clear upon which Element the event was
  // detected:
  element.style.setProperty('--clickedElement', `"${element.tagName.toLowerCase()}"`);
}

// binding the createElement() function as the event-handler
// for the 'click' event:
button.addEventListener('click', createElement);

// iterating over the existing <li> elements and binding the
// event-handler to them:
document.querySelectorAll('#list li').forEach(
  (el) => el.addEventListener('click', removeItem)
);
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body * {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

body [data-tag]::before {
  content: ' (' attr(data-tag) ') ';
  color: #999;
}

h2 {
  align-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.clicked::after {
  content: 'You clicked on the: ' var(--clickedElement, 'span');
  color: limegreen;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: block;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list" data-tag="ul">
  <li data-tag="li">li-element: 0
    <h2 data-tag="h2">h2-element: 0
      <span data-tag="span">span-element: 0</span>
    </h2>
  </li>
  <li data-tag="li">li-element: 1
    <h2 data-tag="h2">h2-element: 1
      <span data-tag="span">span-element: 1</span>
    </h2>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="add">Add &lt;li&gt; elements</button>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7p6m1aL3/1).

Because `Element.closest()` may return `null` in the event of no ancestor matching a supplied CSS Selector, it's more reliable to use `event.currentTarget` since that returns the element to which the event-handler was bound. If that element doesn't exist the event-handler can't be fired (unless it's accidentally removed during the event-handler itself, and then called again after its removal but that's something of an edge-case):

```js
// here we're using a generator function to generate an
// incrementing numeric counter to use for the element-
// id; assigning a default value to the 'initial' variable
// in the event one is not supplied:
let idGenerator = function*(initial = 0) {
    // here we use a horrible approach to allow the
    // function to generate an infinite sequence of
    // of numbers (note this does not cause an
    // infinite loop)
    while (true) {
      // we yield the value of the initial variable,
      // and then increment that value for the next
      // iteration of the generator:
      yield initial++;
    }
  },

  // initialising the generator function:
  idGen = idGenerator(document.querySelectorAll('#list li').length),
  // I don't enjoy typing 'document.createElement(...)'
  // repeatedly, so a helper functiont takes of that for
  // me:
  create = (el) => {
    return document.createElement(el);
  },
  // a reference to a <button> that exists in order to
  // add new contents to the <ul> element:
  button = document.querySelector('#add'),

  // function that will both create, and append those
  // new elements; using Arrow syntax:
  createElement = () => {
    // creating the elements using the helper function:
    const li = create('li'),
      span = create('span'),
      h2 = create('h2'),

      // getting the new id-value from the generator:
      id = idGen.next().value;

    // iterating over the created elements using
    // Array.prototype.forEach() along with an Arrow
    // function:
    [li, span, h2].forEach(
      // 'el' is a reference to the current element in the
      // Array of Elements over which we're iterating:
      (el) => {
        // caching a reference to the type of element:
        let tag = el.tagName.toLowerCase();

        // here we use the Element.dataset API to add a custom
        // data-* attribute and value to the Element, here it's
        // the tag-name of the element (for visualisation
        // purposes later):
        el.dataset.tag = tag;
        // and here we set the text-content of the Element, so
        // that each element has a unique text and is easily
        // identifiable:
        el.textContent = `${tag}-element: ${id}`;
      })

    // appending the child-elements to their parents:
    h2.append(span);
    li.append(h2);

    // binding the removeItem() function as the 'click'
    // event-handler for the <li> element:
    li.addEventListener('click', removeItem);

    // appending the <li> to the <ul>:
    document.querySelector('#list').append(li);
  };

// the 'event' Object is passed automatically from the
// EventTarget.AddEventListener() function:
function removeItem(event) {

  // we get a reference to the element upon which
  // the event-handler was bound and within - or
  // upon - which the event was fired:
  const element = event.currentTarget;
  // here we update the color of that element, in order to show
  // where the click was detected and to more easily illustrate
  // what the 'event.target' is:
  element.style.color = '#f90';

  // here we also assign a class-name to the clicked element:
  element.classList.add('clicked');

  // here we add a custom-property ('CSS variable') to - again -
  // make it instantly clear upon which Element the event was
  // detected:
  element.style.setProperty('--clickedElement', `"${element.tagName.toLowerCase()}"`);
}

// binding the createElement() function as the event-handler
// for the 'click' event:
button.addEventListener('click', createElement);

// iterating over the existing <li> elements and binding the
// event-handler to them:
document.querySelectorAll('#list li').forEach(
  (el) => el.addEventListener('click', removeItem)
);
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body * {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

body [data-tag]::before {
  content: ' (' attr(data-tag) ') ';
  color: #999;
}

h2 {
  align-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.clicked::after {
  content: 'You clicked on the: ' var(--clickedElement, 'span');
  color: limegreen;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: block;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list" data-tag="ul">
  <li data-tag="li">li-element: 0
    <h2 data-tag="h2">h2-element: 0
      <span data-tag="span">span-element: 0</span>
    </h2>
  </li>
  <li data-tag="li">li-element: 1
    <h2 data-tag="h2">h2-element: 1
      <span data-tag="span">span-element: 1</span>
    </h2>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="add">Add &lt;li&gt; elements</button>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7p6m1aL3/2).

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty).
- [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [`Element.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName).
- [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).
- [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [Generator functions `function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).
- [Increment operator (postfix) (`variable++`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment).
- [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- [`while (...) {...}` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).
- [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield).